# MySQL Workbench with Debian Jessie - TCP/IP over SSH does not work

Tags: mysql, debian

### I use to connect with Windows 7 Pro x64 to my MySQL server hosted on a Debian Wheezy with the MySQL Workbench client using the "TCP/IP over SSH" but it does not work on my new server on Debian Jessie, why ?

---

MySQL Workbench config:

```
Connection Name: TEST
Connection Method: Standard TCP/IP over SSH

SSH Hostname: x.x.x.x:22
SSH Username: root
SSH Password: myRootPa$$word
SSH Key File: <NOT-USING-KEYFILE>

MySQL Hostname: 127.0.0.1
MySQL Server Port: 3306
Username: root
Password: myMySQLPa$$word
```

I have double check the IP address/hostname, username and password...

---

Debian Wheezy server config:

root@debian:~# cat /etc/debian_version

```
7.8
```

mysql> select version();

```
+------------------+
| version()        |
+------------------+
| 5.5.40-0+wheezy1 |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

root@debian:~# cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config

```
Port 22
Protocol 2
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
UsePrivilegeSeparation yes

KeyRegenerationInterval 3600
ServerKeyBits 768
SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel INFO
LoginGraceTime 120
PermitRootLogin yes
StrictModes yes
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes

IgnoreRhosts yes
RhostsRSAAuthentication no
HostbasedAuthentication no
PermitEmptyPasswords no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
PrintMotd no
PrintLastLog yes
TCPKeepAlive yes

AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
UsePAM yes
```

Debian Jessie server config:

root@debian:~# cat /etc/debian_version

```
8.0
```

mysql> select version();

```
+-----------------+
| version()       |
+-----------------+
| 5.5.43-0+deb8u1 |
+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

root@debian:~# cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config

```
Port 22
Protocol 2
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
UsePrivilegeSeparation yes

KeyRegenerationInterval 3600
ServerKeyBits 1024
SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel INFO
LoginGraceTime 120
PermitRootLogin yes
StrictModes yes
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes

IgnoreRhosts yes
RhostsRSAAuthentication no
HostbasedAuthentication no
PermitEmptyPasswords no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
PrintMotd no
PrintLastLog yes
TCPKeepAlive yes

AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
UsePAM yes
```

So the man difference is the `ServerKeyBits` between the two sshd_config file...

---

The error MySQL Workbench 6.3.3 give me when I try to connect to the **Debian Jessie** server:

```
Could not connect the SSH Tunnel
Authentication error, unhandled exception caught in tunnel manager, please refer to logs for details
```

The log file:

```
10:00:04 [INF][     SSH tunnel]: Starting tunnel
10:00:04 [INF][     SSH tunnel]: Existing SSH tunnel not found, opening new one
10:00:07 [INF][     SSH tunnel]: Opening SSH tunnel to 10.232.50.15:22
10:00:07 [WRN][sshtunnel.py:_connect_ssh:287]: IOError, probably caused by file C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Roaming\MySQL\Workbench\ssh\known_hosts not found, the message was: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'C:\\Users\\myUser\\AppData\\Roaming\\MySQL\\Workbench\\ssh\\known_hosts'
10:00:07 [ERR][sshtunnel.py:notify_exception_error:233]: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 6.3 CE\sshtunnel.py", line 297, in _connect_ssh
    look_for_keys=has_key, allow_agent=has_key)
  File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 6.3 CE/python/site-packages\paramiko\client.py", line 301, in connect
    t.start_client()
  File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 6.3 CE/python/site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 461, in start_client
    raise e
SSHException: Incompatible ssh peer (no acceptable kex algorithm)

10:00:07 [INF][     SSH tunnel]: TunnelManager.wait_connection authentication error: Authentication error, unhandled exception caught in tunnel manager, please refer to logs for details
10:00:07 [ERR][     SSH tunnel]: Authentication error opening SSH tunnel: Authentication error, unhandled exception caught in tunnel manager, please refer to logs for details
```

---

*More infos:*

The folder "ssh" is not present in:

```
C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Roaming\MySQL\Workbench
```

Firewall rules on both servers:

```
root@debian:~# iptables -vnL

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

I can connect with SSH (KiTTY) on both server...

---

I have tried two different version of MySQL Workbench:

```
Version 6.3.3.0 build 592 (64 bits)
Version 6.0.9.11421 build 1170 (32 bits)
```

These two version works with Debian Wheezy but not with Debian Jessie.
**What am I missing?**

Answer (score 10):

According to https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=74658 the issue presents itself when using openssh 6.7 the python libraries shipped with MySql workbench. While adding the "KexAlgorithms" to the sshd config works, you can update the python libraries that come with MySql Workbench.  This may be handy if you don't have control over the sshd config...

If you scroll down in the bug report, there are instructions to download and copy the paramiko and ecdsa libraries.

Comment: +1. This is the correct answer. Changing the allowed key exchange algorithms in sshd may have security impacts so this shouldn't be done. Updating the client library as suggested in this answer is less invasive and improves the security of the ssh tunnel.

Comment: Hat the same problem with Workbench 6.2 and Debian Jessie.

My Workbench 6.2 CE told me that it was the latest version in Help->Check for Updates. What a lie...

Downloaded Version 6.3 from https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/ and everything works like a charm.

Answer (score 9):

**I have found the solution.**

I added this line to my `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file:

```
KexAlgorithms curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
```

and restarted ssh:
`systemctl restart ssh`

as suggested by this post: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26577494/aptana-sftp-key-exchange

Comment: This certainly allowed access but I am still weary that this is the correct thing to do. There are quite a few Algorithms listed, any idea which is required for MySQL Workbench?

Answer (score 0):

Since there is a lot to scroll through on bigmandan's answer, I think it might make sense to also post it here to make it easier to find.

**For Windows**, this is the fix.
[3 Jun 2015 15:27] Mike Hadrup
Also tested on Windows 10 64 bit with MySQL Workbench 6.3.3.0 (592) msi and noinstall against Debian 8 Jessie with OpenSSH 6.7

- download zip from https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko and unzip
- copy paramiko from paramiko-master to python/site-packages/ (replace existing paramiko)
- download ecdsa-0.13.tar.gz from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ecdsa#downloads and unzip
- copy ecdsa from ecdsa-0.13 to python/site-packages/

You can use 7zip from http://www.7-zip.org/ for the ecdsa-0.13.tar.gz gizpped tar archive.

Note: Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2013 is required on Windows 10 from: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784

**On OS X**, copy paramiko and ecdsa libraries to:
/Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Resources/libraries

Answer (score 0):

because there are two method to connect to mysql. the time when you install mysql and that time it ask which way you wana go 1st is unix sock which is very served and gives you good performance and the 2nd one is TCP/ip and please do check the privileges either you can connect to you db remotely just used some other ip if no then you and enable to the security feature in mysql

Comment: The Unix-socket interface to MySQL is only usable by clients on the same machine; this question is about a client on a different machine which must use TCP/IP (and optionally, as in the question, SSH).

Answer (score 0):

In linux (and TOTALLY sidestepping the issue), I found it simpler/cleaner to manually create my own ssh tunnel for mysql-workbench to use:

> ssh root@host -L 3307:localhost:3306

This creates an ssh tunnel from your local port 3307 to remote's local port 3306. **So you just configure mysql-workbench to connect to localhost:3307**.